# How to set custom function for AcceleratDecelerateInterpolator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

I'm trying to make it so that one of the ImageViews in my activity undergoes a spinning animation where it accelerates quickly and slowly spins to a stop, as if friction is causing it to slow to a stop. I have a good function for this, but I do not know how to make it so that AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator uses this function.

So far my code for this is:

```
AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator anim = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

float deg = image.getRotation() + 360F;
image.animate().rotation(deg).setInterpolator(anim);
```

I have seen another thread for this, but I am not quite sure how to implement the code in the solutions as I am still fairly new. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help you. [Customize it according to your need & then use it directly by just making an object & setting with any view.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015656/10357086)

Comment: @SweetD3v I had a couple of questions about this actually. Where do I actually add this code? what is getInterpolation?